# How do I add command line launch arguments to a Release target in a CMake-managed C++ project in MSVC 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, release

My goal is to run e.g. `MyTarget.exe "C:\Users\MHebes\config.json` from MSVC.

I can do this in Debug mode, but can't get it to work in Release.

If I right-click on my top-level CMakeLists.txt, I can see the `launch.vs.json` for the current open folder:

*..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_45505961\OpenFolder\launch_schema.json*:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyTarget.exe (apps\\MyTarget\\Debug\\MyTarget.exe)",
      "name": "Debug launch target for MyTarget",
      "args": [
        "C:/Users/MHebes/config.json"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't fully understand this in the first place, since the [launch.vs.json docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/launch-vs-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-160) don't mention anything about a `"configurations"` list but this was how it was auto-populated when I added a new configuration. Regardless, this works in debug mode—the "Debug launch target for MyTarget" option shows up in the `Select Startup Item...` list when `Debug` is selected in the dropdown.

I have added a `Release`/`RelWithDebugInfo` configuration to my `CMakeSettings.json`.

But when I actually switch the build to `Release`, the `Select Startup Item...` list is only populated with default CMakeTargets.

How do I add command-line launch arguments to Release builds?

My end goal is that when I Start Debugging in Release mode, it will build a Release exe and run it with some args.

Comment: Also, `buildConfigurations` seems like the right property but the docs say its "A key-value pair that specifies the name of the build mode to apply the configurations. For example, Debug or Release and the configurations to use according to the selected build mode." I have no idea what that means, since it's typed as an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I added another configuration with a different target:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyTarget.exe (apps\\MyTarget\\Debug\\MyTarget.exe)",
      "name": "Debug launch target for MyTarget",
      "args": [
        "C:/Users/MHebes/config.json"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyTarget.exe (apps\\MyTarget\\RelWithDebInfo\\MyTarget.exe)",
      "name": "RelWithDebInfo launch target for MyTarget",
      "args": [
        "C:/Users/MHebes/config.json"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The Microsoft Docs page on [Configure CMake debugging sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configure-cmake-debugging-sessions?view=msvc-160#customize-debugger-settings) says:

> `projectTarget`: Specifies the CMake target to invoke when building the project. Visual Studio autopopulates this property if you enter launch.vs.json from the Debug Menu or Targets View. **This value must match the name of an existing debug target listed in the Startup Item dropdown.**

Since Visual studio populates the Startup list with names that include the path to the executable, and because that path is dependent on the configuration name (i.e. `buildRoot` in `CMakeSettings.json` includes `${name}` in the path by default), this explains why `projectTarget` must include the configuration path.

This seems like an insane interface to me. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you hack up your CMakeLists.txt to put targets in configuration-dependent paths?

Comment: @John No, I have a pretty standard CMake tree. My target is just called `MyTarget`. I wasn’t using visual studio directly until recently, just the cmake CLI. Those target names are just what visual studio is autopopulating the target list with. I don’t know why.

Comment: Needing the configuration type in the path to a target does not match my experience of using Visual Studio's native CMake support.