# In Visual Studio 2022, when launching a CMake-based project from the IDE, what is the syntax to have per-configuration settings in launch.vs.json?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Currently my launch.vs.json file looks like the following

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "my_exe.exe",
      "name": "my_exe.exe",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "%PATH%;C:\\libraries\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\bin;C:\\libraries\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\debug\\bin"
      },
      "args": [ "some cmd line arg" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to make the PATH env variable only include the path for debug or release based on the configuration selected and have different command line arguments based on the configuration.

[There was a self-answered question pertaining to VS 2019 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077547/how-do-i-add-command-line-launch-arguments-to-a-release-target-in-a-cmake-manage), that suggests setting the target to be the exe in directories that are dependent on the configuration, but (1) this seems like a bad solution and (2) it seems to use undocumented syntax anyway, i.e. <some_exe> ( <some_path_to_the_exe> ), and I'd like a more official/definitive solution.

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/launch-vs-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-170) says this about a JSON field called `buildConfigurations`

> A key-value pair that specifies the name of the build mode to apply
> the configurations. For example, Debug or Release and the
> configurations to use according to the selected build mode.

However I have several problems with this description:

1. Do they mean *an array* of key/value pairs?
2. What is the syntax of the key/value pairs? Two element arrays? Objects with a `key` field and a `value` field?
3. Would the above be in place of a `configurations` array?
4. If they don't mean an array of key/value pairs in place of the `configurations` array then what do they mean? The key sounds like it is "Debug" or "Release" but what is the value?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if there is a way to do this, but I understand a little more how this file works and can work around the problem. Basically the thing to understand is whatever you put in the `name` field of the configuration JSON objects will show up in the dropdown of Visual Studio's "select startup item" combo box.

So there may or may not be a way to make the default selection there be dependent on the selected configuration but in any case you can just make items in the `launch.vs.json` for each configuration and select the correct one manually when launching your program from the IDE.

That is, make your `launch.vs.json` look like

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "my_exe.exe",
      "name": "My Release build",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "%PATH%;C:\\libraries\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\bin"
      },
      "args": [ "some cmd line args for Release" ]
    } , 
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "my_exe.exe",
      "name": "My Debug build",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "%PATH%;C:\\libraries\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\Debug\\bin"
      },
      "args": [ "some cmd line args for Debug" ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

And then manually choose either "My Debug build" or "My Release build" based on the configuration you have selected.

Probably, the way that the `buildConfigurations` field is supposed to work is it is an array of key/value pairs in the toplevel JSON object that maps Debug/Release to *the names of* items in the `configurations` array, e.g. something like

```
"buildConfigurations": [
  {
    "key": "Debug",
    "value": [ "My Debug build" ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Release",
    "value": [ "My Release build" ]
  }
]
```

given the above `configurations` array, but this is just my guess as I couldn't get it to work.