# How to expand the current CMake build type in Visual Studio's launch.vs.json?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-debugging

**This is *not* about Visual Studio Code. It's not about `launch.json`.** This question is about **Visual Studio** and its `launch.vs.json` file.

In [VS 2022's `launch.vs.json` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/launch-vs-schema-reference-cpp?view=msvc-170), in a custom debug target, how can I reference the current CMake build type? I need something like this:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyProgram.exe (app\\MyProgram\\MyProgram.exe)",
      "name": "MyProgram.exe (app\\MyProgram\\MyProgram.exe)",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "PATH",
          "value": "D:\\my-dlls-for-build-type-${cmake.buildType}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But `${cmake.buildType}` is not recognized here. I get this error: `Var:${cmake.buildType} failed evaluation`.

Comment: i'm not sure you can. I ask a related question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77009615/in-visual-studio-2022-when-launching-a-cmake-based-project-from-the-ide-what-i
see my answer there for a work-around

Comment: @jwezorek Thanks, I change those configurations often so I'll just rely on search and replace in one config instead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `${cmake.configurationType}`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this:

[Reference keys in CMakeSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configure-cmake-debugging-sessions?view=msvc-170#reference-keys-in-cmakesettingsjson)

From the official document:

> Environment variables defined in CMakeSettings.json can also be used
> in launch.vs.json using the syntax ${env.VARIABLE_NAME}.

Is this what you want?

Comment: `${cmake.configurationType}` worked, than you!